# How to render index page with Vuejs using Node + Express

Tags: node.js, express, vue.js, vuejs2, ejs

I'm building a small application with Vuejs + Node but currently have to run 2 servers in dev:

- my node server: `nodemon server.js`
- and Vuejs built in script: `npm run dev` which runs webpack-dev-server

When I try to deploy I can't figure out how to render the index.html page with my vuejs app loaded.

On my server I'm simply serving my index.html file:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/'));
```

Index.html loads as a blank page.

I tried running `npm run build` and get the following message, but can't figure out how to have my app initiated from there.

[image]

Here's my index.html file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
    <title>Startup app</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <!-- built files will be auto injected -->

  </body>
</html>
```

I know the js file with the built is not being injected, but not sure how to do that part. Could someone please help?

Comment: I am facing the problem. Were you able to figure it out?

Answer (score 1):

Try to create a folder named `public` then  place your `index.html` there. 
Then serve your `index.html` by:

```
app.use(express.static('public'));
```

Comment: index.html is loading just fine with my example code, but the issue is that I can't figure out how to inject the vuejs files in prod (without running `npm run dev`)

Answer (score 0):

You can use ejs to render the html file in server just create folder Views and create file Home.ejs and `npm i --save ejs` after that  require ejs in your server and create get request to render this file in your server i faced this problem

```
app.set('view engine', 'ejs') 
app.get('/', function(req, res){ 
    res.render('Home')})
```